# How do you update a Mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, insert, database

- Add an element to it
- Update a value of an element

Comment: I really have to say RTFM here. These are basic operations covered by any introduction to mongo document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

Answer (score 1):

It all depends which program language you are using. 
If you are using Mongo shell,
you can just do

> db.user.save({username:"tom"});

Update will be similar concept,

> db.users.update({b:'q'}, {$set:{a:1}}, false, true)
>   If you are familiar with SQL script, check this out

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart